# Connectivity Issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Wi-Fi Network Drops

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager

I am encountering a **persistent** issue with my Wi-Fi network on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. After connecting to a Wi-Fi network, it works fine for an *undetermined period*, but then it becomes inaccessible on my laptop. When I try to access the network, it seems as if it's no longer available. However, the same network **works perfectly** on other devices like my smartphone, and I have never encountered this problem on Windows.

Additionally, during the Ubuntu installation, I selected the *minimal* installation option, thinking it was the best choice, but it appears that this might not have been the case.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this connectivity problem. If you need more information about my system or network configuration, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help.

> Note: I installed Ubuntu for the first time approximately a month ago, so I may not be very familiar with how everything works yet.

### Specifications and outputs

```bash
# sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       descrizione: Ethernet interface
       prodotto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fornitore: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id fisico: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nome logico: enp3s0
       versione: 15
       seriale: b4:a9:fc:8e:37:3d
       capacità: 1Gbit/s
       larghezza: 64 bits
       orologio: 33MHz
       capacità: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configurazione: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-32-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       risorse: irq:16 ioport:3000(dimensione=256) memoria:b4404000-b4404fff memoria:b4400000-b4403fff
  *-network
       descrizione: Interfaccia Wireless
       prodotto: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       fornitore: Qualcomm Atheros
       id fisico: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       nome logico: wlp4s0
       versione: 31
       seriale: 80:30:49:0c:43:5b
       larghezza: 64 bits
       orologio: 33MHz
       capacità: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configurazione: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.2.0-32-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=151.97.159.244 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       risorse: irq:142 memoria:b4000000-b41fffff
```

```bash
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:a031 Quanta Computer, Inc. VGA WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 30fa:0400  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.